# Finding stationary point of vector-valued function

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, stationary-point

I'm trying to find a stationary point of the function $r(u) = \gamma(\begin{matrix}
\alpha -u_1+u_1^2u_2\\
\beta - u_1^2u_2 \end{matrix})$ , with $ \alpha , \beta , \gamma > 0 $

I have taken partial derivatives with respect to $u_1$ and $u_2$ and got that $$\partial_,u_1 = \gamma(\begin{matrix}
-1 +2u_1u_2\\
-2u_1u_2 \end{matrix})$$

$$\partial_,u_2 = \gamma(\begin{matrix}
u_1^2\\
-u_1^2 \end{matrix})$$

Therefore from the second one I came to the conclusion that $u_1$ = $0$ and that the stationary point was $u =(\begin{matrix}
\alpha \gamma\\
\beta \gamma \end{matrix})$. However I'm not sure if this is correct as if $u_1=0$ then the $x$ component of $\partial_,u_1$ is still non-zero.

Comment: What means stationary points on a function $r:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

Comment: A stationary point is when the derivative of the function is $0$ at that point?

Comment: Then both components derivative should be simultaneously $0$ at those points?

Comment: Yes i think so. But this is where I get confused. Lets look at the first component. $r_1(u) = \gamma ( \alpha - u_1 + u_1^2u_2)$. Then for the derivative of this component to be $0$ at a point we require the  partial derivatives of $r_1u$ with respect to $u_1$ and $u_2$ to both be 0. However, we have that $\partial_,u_1 r_1u= \gamma (-1 + 2u_1u_2)$ whereas $\partial_,u_2 r_1u = \gamma (u_1^2)$ Surely these can't both be $0$ for non-negative $\gamma$?

Comment: So calling $u_1=x,u_2=y$ we have $\left\{\gamma  (2 x y-1)=0,\gamma  x^2=0,-2 \gamma  x y=0,-\gamma  x^2=0\right\}$ four equations and two unknowns.